# Phonegap camera, works on Android, nothing happens on iPhone

Tags: android, cordova

I'm writing an `PhoneGap` app, where I'm using the `Camera API` to take a picture.

I've managed to get it working on my `Android` devices, but when I try to use the same code for my `iPhone` app nothing happens. No callback at all; not success, nor fail..

My code follows:

```
function captureCamera() {
    displayWaitingMessage("Ansluter kamera"); //Diplaying a div with a message that we're connecting the camera
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCameraSuccess, onCameraFail, { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
}

function onCameraSuccess(imageURI) {
    saveImage(imageURI);
}

function onCameraFail(message) {
    myAlert("Oj, nu gick något fel!"); //using navigator.notification.alert in an setTimeout(thelaertfunction,0);
    hideAllOverlays();
}

function saveImage(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, safeDomain+"/common/mobApp/ajax/uploadImage", win, fail, options);
}

function win(r) {
    myAlert("Din bild har sparats");
    loadUrl("/common/mobApp/viewImage?degrees=360&reload=true");
}

function fail(error) {
    myAlert("Det gick inte att spara din bild.");
    loadUrl("/common/mobApp/viewImage");
}
```

Any ideas?

(using **Phonegap 2.5.0** on the **iOS version, 2.7.0** on **Android**, though it worked just as well with **2.3.0** previously)

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out my cordova-2.5.0.js was in the wrong folder :-/